# Error "SP excludes both SAML 2 name identifier formats" while validating my SP metadata

Tags: authentication, single-sign-on, metadata, saml

I'm getting mentioned error while validating below SP metadata in "https://validator.safire.ac.za". What could be the reason?

Metadata:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<md:EntityDescriptor ID="ONELOGIN_ebfb2530-b00e-4059-8cd2-55305472de69" cacheDuration="PT604800S" entityID="https://example.com/sp/SAML/27987238942342/metadata" validUntil="2020-08-27T09:33:08Z" xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata">
    <md:SPSSODescriptor AuthnRequestsSigned="true" WantAssertionsSigned="true" protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
        <md:KeyDescriptor use="signing">
            <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <ds:X509Data>
                    <ds:X509Certificate>-----
                        cert
                        ----
</ds:X509Certificate>
                </ds:X509Data>
            </ds:KeyInfo>
        </md:KeyDescriptor>
        <md:KeyDescriptor use="encryption">
            <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <ds:X509Data>
                    <ds:X509Certificate>---
                        cert
                        ----
</ds:X509Certificate>
                </ds:X509Data>
            </ds:KeyInfo>
        </md:KeyDescriptor>
        <md:SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="https://example.com/sp/SAML/27987238942342/logout/callback"/>
        <md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified</md:NameIDFormat>
        <md:AssertionConsumerService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="https://example.com/sp/SAML/27987238942342/callback" index="1"/>
    </md:SPSSODescriptor>
</md:EntityDescriptor>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems tha the 'South African Idenity Federation' applies stricter rules as the SAML spec and they do not accept NameId format `urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified`. It seems they only support NameId formats  `urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent` and `urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient`. It's a platform specific issue but not a general SAML2 issue.

Comment: Thank you Bernhard for this information. It really helps.